# building a jquery menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I have built a jquery menu.

However it's not very elegant and rather clunky. For example, When you click 'menu' , it snaps open and snaps closed very quickly.

Also, if you open the menu and hover over a link,  clicking to the left or right of the link will cause the menu will snap shut again

please may someone help me make this a little more elegant?  I have tried using  a slide effect, but when the user hovers over the menu, it creates a bouncing effect (The menu opens and closes continuously )

HERE is my code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s94xhnw6/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $('.submenu').fadeToggle('1000');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: #34495E;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #2C3E50;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #34495E;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #34495E;
  clear: both;
  margin-left: 66px;
}

.submenu {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #6D767F;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  display: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 11px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #FFF;
}

ul li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #719ECC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <!-- START HEADER -->
  <ul>
    <li>menu</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="submenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Mountain Bike</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">gopro</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Shoei Helmet</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Don't just place a fiddle link in the question. And certainly don't circumvent the _"Please place your code in the question"_ popup like that!

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/s94xhnw6/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $('.submenu').slideToggle('600'); /* using slideToggle will make the list slide elegantly */
  });
});
```

```css
/* some changes to make it look elegant. */

body {
  font-family: helvetica;
}

.menu {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background: #34495E;
  border: 0px;
  border: 2px solid #2C3E50;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #34495E;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px #34495E;
}

.submenu {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #6D767F;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  display: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 11px;
  margin: 0px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #FFF;
}

ul li a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.submenu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #719ECC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <!-- START HEADER -->
  <ul>
    <li>menu</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="submenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Mountain Bike</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">gopro</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Shoei Helmet</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It snaps open because of all the 'fading' you've been doing, instead use `slideDown()` to open menu, which gives it a very decent entry.. and `slideUp()` to close it.

Instead of click, use `mouseenter()` event to open and `mouseleave()` event to close it.

Remove extra `margins` and `paddings` from the `ul` and `li`.

And it's ready to be used as new.

The bouncing effect (The menu opens and closes continuously ) of the `slide event` that you talk about is easily rectified by using `stop()`. When `.stop()` is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped.

I've kept the code simple for you to understand... there are many more ways to do the same thing.

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/s94xhnw6/3/

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.menu').on('mouseenter', function () {
        $('.submenu').slideDown();
    });

     $('.menu').on('mouseleave', function () {
        $('.submenu').stop().slideUp();
    });    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are a learner use this code

```
 ul {
      height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;   
    }
```

jquery

```
$ (document).ready(function() {

    $ ('.menu').click(function() {
    $('.submenu').slideToggle('1000');
});

});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s94xhnw6/)

Comment: You might want to explain what you're doing there, considering OP is a "learner"

Comment: Thakns guys, I've been learning jquery for 3 hours, so I'm a little shaky.  I used slide toggle and amended my css. Everything works fine!  Thanks

Comment: rate it if my answer is helpful to you